# Why Delete or Put Mapping same can be achieved though Get or POST?

Tags: rest

@RestController
public class TestController {

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public List<String> testApi() {
    return (List<String>) Arrays.asList("one","two","three");
}
@PostMapping("/test")
public String addApi(@RequestBody String name) {
    return name;
}
@DeleteMapping("/test")
public String deleteApi(@RequestBody String name) {
    return name;
}
```

}

From above code snippet, Using GET Mapping or POST Mapping, we can implement all crud operation on any resource/object. Why we need DELETE / PUT/PATCH. i can understand conceptually .in Practically how it will use full. Can anyone answer Please?

Tags

Comment: Note: RequestBody with a DeleteMapping is suspect.  See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.5
"content received in a DELETE request has no generally defined semantics....".  Doesn't mean that you can't do it, but you should understand why you shouldn't before you do.

Answer (score 0):

> Using GET Mapping or POST Mapping, we can implement all crud operation on any resource/object

Yup - that's exactly right.  In the 1990s, that's exactly how the web worked; it was catastrophically successful.

> Why we need DELETE / PUT/PATCH.

The benefit of having these methods: they are more *specific* than POST.  That, in turn, means that general purpose components can take advantage of the additional constraints on these methods to do useful things.

For example: both PUT and DELETE have an "idempotent" constraint.  This is powerful on an unreliable network because it means that the general purpose component knows that it can automatically repeat the request if it times out waiting for a response, without having to concern itself with any loss of property that may result.

[PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.html) is interesting primarily for its impact on [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.html#section-3); servers can advertise that a resource supported patching, and which patch document formats are supported.

So if we make a very small change to a very large document, our document editor can query the remote server to discover if we can send a small patch document rather than sending the entire revised document.